# android image "viewer" app

Tags: android, image, gallery

I am trying to create an android app that will let me display images fullscreen with next and previous buttons on top to change between them.

Can anybody point me to some tutorials where i can find instructions on something similar?

If not, what is the best method to use to get the images into the app? I have tried several ways from creating object classes for the images and instantiating it with a drawable in each using the Bitmap Factory to return the image but that won't work.

I am a beginner to android and could really use reference material but can't find anything useful that covers this subject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a newbie myself I've been working with this and it's very simple. Here is some code (maybe there is a better way but this is the way I figured out how to do it):

```
package com.imageviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    int image_index = 0;
    private static final int MAX_IMAGE_COUNT = 3;

    private int[] mImageIds = {
            R.raw.image1,
            R.raw.image2,
            R.raw.image3
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnPrevious = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous_btn);
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);       
        Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

        showImage();        

    }

    private void showImage() {

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);             
        imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[image_index]);       

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case (R.id.previous_btn):

                image_index--;

                if (image_index == -1) {                    
                    image_index = MAX_IMAGE_COUNT - 1;                  
                }

                showImage();

            break;

            case (R.id.next_btn):

                image_index++;

                if (image_index == MAX_IMAGE_COUNT) {               
                image_index = 0;                
            }

                showImage();

            break;      

        }

    }
}
```

And this is the `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previous_btn"
    android:layout_width="124dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Previous"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_btn"
    android:layout_width="124dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous_btn" 
    android:text="Next"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/previous_btn"
    />         

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. What is driving me crazy is that my 3 or 4 test projects essentially did this exactly the same way, but they would either forceclose or not work some other way. Thank you for saving me from tearing my hair out. The part I see different from mine is the onClickListener, could you why it has to be set to "this", just so I can try get a more complete understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: Being new to Android, I really cannot explain why it has to be set to "this". I *think* the "this" just references your class, or main activity. Like in the above example, "this" could be replaced by "ImageViewExample.this" and it would work the same. I learned the above from reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: Thanks again. Most helpful and kind.

Comment: @Hamid when you you call `setOnClickListener()`, you pass an instance of `OnClickListener.class` (or a class extending it) to it. You could have written something like `setOnClickListener(new MyOwnClickListener())`. In the example of ShadowGod, look how the class is declared: `... implements OnClickListener`. This means the `ImageViewExampleActivity` is also a `OnClickListener`. The keyword `this` or `ImageViewExampleActivity.this` both reference the current class named `ImageViewExampleActivity`. This is not specific to the Android SDK at all. You have to study Java a bit more.

Comment: Heh, this is an ooooold question! I now work almost exclusively as an Android developer. My how things change in a couple of years.

Answer (score 8):

This is a picture viewer solution with grid view of picture resources from which you can choose a picture and display it as a single picture.In this single picture view, that is accomplished with PictureViewer.java you can browse threw resource pictures using left and right button. You can also return to grid view that is accomplished with HelloGridViewActivity.java. ImageAdapter.java is used to define grid view resources and methods. Hope this helps:

HelloGridViewActivity.java:

```
package com.example.hellogridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class HelloGridViewActivity extends Activity {

private long prev=0,next= 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


            prev = ImageAdapter.getPrevItemId(position);
            next = ImageAdapter.getNextItemId(position);

            showImage(gridview.getAdapter().getItemId(position),position);


        }
    });

}
private void showImage(long id, int pos){
    Intent pictureViewer = new Intent(this, PictureViewer.class);
    pictureViewer.putExtra("pictureId",id );
    pictureViewer.putExtra("picturePosition", pos);
    pictureViewer.putExtra("picturePrevId", prev);
    pictureViewer.putExtra("pictureNextId", next);

    startActivityForResult(pictureViewer,0);

  }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.hellogridview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

public static long getPrevItemId(int position) {
    if(--position<0) position = 21;
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

public static long getNextItemId(int position) {
    if(++position>21) position = 0;
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private static Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
  };
}
```

PictureViewer.java:

```
package com.example.hellogridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class PictureViewer extends Activity {

long picItem,picPrevItem,picNextItem;
int picPosition;
private ImageView m_vwImage;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_layout);


    //citanje podataka prosledjenih ovoj aktivnosti
    //namera koja je pokrenula ovu aktivnost
    Intent i = getIntent();

    picItem = i.getLongExtra("pictureId", -1);
    picPrevItem = i.getLongExtra("picturePrevId", -1);
    picNextItem = i.getLongExtra("pictureNextId", -1);
    picPosition = i.getIntExtra("picturePosition", -1);
    m_vwImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);


    //menjamo ulazne vrednosti da bi ih takve prosledili kao povratne
    Log.i("Nemanja", "picItem" + picItem);

    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable((int)picItem);
    m_vwImage.setImageDrawable(image);


    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.return_button);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            finish();   
        }
    });     

    Button leftButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_button);
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Drawable imagePrev = getResources().getDrawable((int)picPrevItem);
            m_vwImage.setImageDrawable(imagePrev);

            if(--picPosition<0) picPosition = 21;
            picPrevItem = (ImageAdapter.getPrevItemId(picPosition));
            picNextItem = (ImageAdapter.getNextItemId(picPosition));

        }
    }); 

    Button rightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button);
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Drawable imageNext = getResources().getDrawable((int)picNextItem);      
            m_vwImage.setImageDrawable(imageNext);

            if(++picPosition>21) picPosition = 0;
            picNextItem = (ImageAdapter.getNextItemId(picPosition));
            picPrevItem = (ImageAdapter.getPrevItemId(picPosition));
        }
    }); 
}
```

}

HelloGridView Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hellogridview"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HelloGridViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PictureViewer"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```