# Android Image viewer app test

Tags: android, image, viewer, image-viewer

I am trying to follow the link below for the code for a Image viewing app in android.

[android image "viewer" app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850795/android-image-viewer-app/3851161#3851161?newreg=df1b63a0e6f94a4d913c3c30ae173db9)

But I am getting an error with the r.raw.image1. (also on raw.image2 and image3). I have saved the images in the asset folder. Error says raw cannot be resolved or is not a field. I have checked various documentations for this but am unable to understand what i am doing wrong. The code is exactly the same as in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your image into res/raw folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no raw folder in res. Even if I create one, it still does not recognise it.

Comment: Make sure the image name in raw folder and java code is same and just clean your project,  then check.